# How can I Preserve Clicked Country States in amCharts 5 Map on Page Reload?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, local-storage, amcharts

I'm very new to HTML, and I'm currently working on a personal project with an interactive amCharts map. When a country is clicked, it changes colour, marking it "active." I am struggling to keep the countries "active" between web reloads. (I am mainly using this code to make an interactive notion widget for my travel page)

I've tried using local storage to preserve these clicked states across page reloads for personal use, but I couldn't get it to work.

I've used localstorage successfully on a button I coded before to keep its state if it's clicked or not between web reloads.

I couldn't find clear guidance in amCharts documentation on how to achieve this. Can anyone provide insights or code examples for storing and retrieving the active states of clicked countries using local storage or another method?

The code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive Polygon Map</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        #chartdiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Resources -->
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/map.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <script>
    
        am5.ready(function () {
            var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

            root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

            var chart = root.container.children.push(am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
                panX: "rotateX",
                panY: "translateY",
                projection: am5map.geoNaturalEarth1()
            }));

            var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
                geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow,
                exclude: ["AQ"]
            }));

            chart.chartContainer.set("background", am5.Rectangle.new(root, {
                fill: am5.color(0x191919),
                fillOpacity: 1.0
            }));

            polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
                tooltipText: "{name}",
                toggleKey: "active",
                interactive: true,
                fill: am5.color("#FFD6E6"),
            });

            polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.states.create("hover", {
                fill: am5.color("#DEB4C6")
            });

            polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.states.create("active", {
                fill: am5.color("#B9CCB1")
            });

            // Function to handle when a country is clicked
            function handleCountryClick(event) {
                var polygon = event.target;
                var isActive = polygon.isActive;
                polygon.isActive = !isActive;
            }

            // Add a click event listener to handle country clicks
            polygonSeries.mapPolygons.events.on("hit", handleCountryClick);

            // Set clicking on "water" to zoom out
            chart.chartContainer.get("background").events.on("click", function () {
                chart.goHome();
            });

            // Add zoom control
            var zoomControl = chart.set("zoomControl", am5map.ZoomControl.new(root, {}));
            var homeButton = zoomControl.children.moveValue(am5.Button.new(root, {
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10,
                icon: am5.Graphics.new(root, {
                    svgPath: "M16,8 L14,8 L14,16 L10,16 L10,10 L6,10 L6,16 L2,16 L2,8 L0,8 L8,0 L16,8 Z M16,8",
                    fill: am5.color(0xffffff)
                })
            }), 0);

            homeButton.events.on("click", function () {
                chart.goHome();
            });

            // Make stuff animate on load
            chart.appear(1000, 100)

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First use below function get the map name where the click in below example use the USA map
 var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
   polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
     // zoom to an object
     ev.target.series.chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
    
     // get object info
     //state_map_clicked = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.name
     state_map_clicked = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.id
   
     //Get Sate map clicked name 
     console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.id);
     
   });
//once map name clicked store this into the normal global variable and 
// Use below the include the map

includeState.push(getStates)

Load the map again based on the previous data
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#region_select').change(function(){
            let get_dropdown_response = $(this).val();
            //alert(get_dropdown_response);
            let includeState = [];
            includeState.push(get_dropdown_response);
            disposeUSAmap(includeState);
  });

  $('#national_state').click(function(){
    disposeUSAmap(["US-AL", "US-AK", "US-AZ", "US-AR", "US-CA", "US-CO", "US-CT", "US-DE", "US-FL", "US-GA", "US-HI", "US-ID", "US-IL", "US-IN", "US-IA", "US-KS", "US-KY", "US-LA", "US-ME", "US-MD", "US-MA", "US-MI", "US-MN", "US-MS", "US-MO", "US-MT", "US-NE", "US-NV", "US-NH", "US-NJ", "US-NM", "US-NY", "US-NC", "US-ND", "US-OH", "US-OK", "US-OR", "US-PA", "US-RI", "US-SC", "US-SD", "US-TN", "US-TX", "US-UT", "US-VT", "US-VA", "US-WA", "US-WV", "US-WI", "US-WY", "US-DC"]);
  });
});
```